# What is a fast algorithm for mesh partition?

Tags: algorithm, computational-geometry

I'm writing some code to render terrain data. For huge meshes, I would like to partition the mesh into submeshes. In order to help camera culling, I would like an algorithm to do the following:

1. Take a mesh (vertices, indexed triangles) and partition it into 2
2. If we project all points onto XZ plane and take the area of the
   bounds of each mesh, I would like to minimize the sum of the area of
   their 2D bounds.

Does anyone know a fast algorithm for doing this?

Answer (score 0):

You got several options to do that:

Option 1: use a graph partitioning algorithm, for instance Scotch and Metis,
they got some options to minimize the "communication cost", that corresponds to the length of the boundaries between your segments:

- http://www.labri.fr/perso/pelegrin/scotch/
- http://glaros.dtc.umn.edu/gkhome/metis/metis/overview

Option 2: If you can leave with suboptimal boundary lengths, then you can spatially sort your triangles along a Hilbert curve, and then split the sorted sequence into the number of segments that you wanted. It is much much faster than the graph partitioning algorithms above (but may generate less compact segments). You can find implementations of spatial sort in Geogram and in CGAL:

- http://alice.loria.fr/software/geogram/doc/html/mesh__reorder_8h.html
- http://doc.cgal.org/latest/Spatial_sorting/index.html